# How to refer to a structured table without referring to its sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

In VBA I know that I can refer to a structured table via this way:

```
  Set Tbl = Sheets("MySheetName").ListObjects("MyTblName")
```

Then do Tbl.XXX where .XXX can be .Name, .Range, etc.

However, I want to refer to this table without referring to the Sheet name, so that the macro does not break if the sheet name changes.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could use the sheet code name which can only be changed via the VBE.

Comment: Like this: Worksheets(1).List..

Comment: @Wizhi That's worse.  That will change not only if the sheetname changes, but also if the sheet position changes.

Comment: Is cycling through sheets to find the correct one an option, that's what I use when the sheet name and position are variable.

Comment: @Wizhi  No.  Just use the `CodeName`.  eg.  `Sheet1.ListObjects("myTblName")`

Comment: Is it the same behavior if you want to use it for range? `Sheet1.Range(....)` instead of `ws.Range(...)`. Thanks for sharing knowledge!

Comment: @Wizhi I suggest you read the VBA help topic for the `Worksheet.CodeName` property, to gain a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, will do that :)!!

Comment: How do you imagine referring to table without sheet name? 1) ListObject always belongs to some sheet, so you can't avoid referring to sheet. 2) What if two tables on different sheets have same name?

Answer (score 3):

After some research I found something that is not a perfect solution.
You can make use of the Range function in VBA like this:

```
Set tbl = Range("TableName[#All]")
```

However this is not a ListObject but a Range. You can also do other references like:

the body of the structured table (excluding headers)

```
Range("TableName")
```

Column called "MyColumn" of the body

```
Range("TableName[MyColumn]")
```

etc.

Then you call something like:
tbl.ListObject to refer to the structured table where the range is found.

The cool thing is that Range() will always work on the ActiveWorkbook, so you can be in WorkBook B and open a macro in Workbook A and it will still run on Workbook B

Source: https://peltiertech.com/structured-referencing-excel-tables/

Answer (score 1):

Why not refer to the sheet's "internal" name instead of its visible name?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to refer to a table (name "tbl_Function") in an unknown worksheet, here is what you can do:

```
Set rng4= Range("tbl_Function[#All]")                      ' range of table
sh = rng4.Parent.Name                                      ' name of the worksheet where the table is placed
tbl = Sheets(sh).ListObjects("tbl_Function").Range.Value   ' take the whole table
```

Hope it helps. Piotr

Answer (score 0):

If your table is on the ActiveSheet, you can use it like:

```
Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTblName")
```

Comment: What if it's not on the active sheet?

Comment: I don't know if I can call it a "good pratice" but when I work with heavy VBA project. I assign all my sheets names in a separate module as public variable with others constants.
After that, if a sheet name change I don't have to recode all the project and the good sheet stay activated if correctly updated in the declaration module.
(I don't see how to avoid activation. Some basic function are very capricious with this, like the simple "Range")

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem of how to protect my code is the sheet name of the the table changed.

I built on Piotr's excellent solution and developed these simplified procedures:-

```
Private Function connectTable(nmTbl As String) As Range
    Set connectTable = Sheets(Range(nmTbl).Parent.Name).ListObjects(nmTbl).DataBodyRange
End Function


Private Sub clearTable(tbl As Range)
    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
        ' MsgBox "already cleared"
    ElseIf tbl.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        'MsgBox "about to delete " & tbl.Rows.Count & " rows"
        tbl.Rows.Delete
    End If
End Sub

' Example how to call the above procedures
Public Sub genCashFlow()
Dim tabDetailCF As Range
Dim nmSheetTabDetailCF As String
Dim tabAsset As Range

    Set tabAsset = connectTable("tabAsset")
    Set tabDetailCF = connectTable("tabDetailCF")
    
    Call clearTable(tabDetailCF)

End Sub
```